# How to Create Instance of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am making a program that when the user clicks the button the asynctask is called in onclick. But everytime the user clicks the button the text changes... How can i implement something that i can call just to utilize the async method.

Here is a example of what i mean

```
        public void  Talk(){        








         text1.setText("Welcome what is your name?");

    respond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = edit.getText().toString();
            new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>(){

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                     try {                 
                         Thread.sleep(850);             
                         } catch (InterruptedException e) {                         
                             e.printStackTrace();             
                             }            
                         return null;
                }
                 @Override         
                 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {             
                    text1.setText("Nice to meet you "+name);
                    dismissDialog(typeBar);
                     }


                     @Override        
                     protected void onPreExecute() { 
                         typeBar = 0;
                         showDialog(typeBar);

        }

        }.execute((Void)null);

        }
    });






}
    }
```

So as you can see evertime the user presses the button the text changes. It will definitely be to tedious to type the ayncTask method EVERYTIME the button is clicked. Anyone

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't create an `asyntask` class, and you can create an object. but, you should carefully, each object just can use only one time. if you want to use again, you must create other instance